# Problema de colocacion en CSS

Tags: html, css

estoy teniendo un problema en cuanto al posicionamiento de un elemento

dentro de una caja. El problema seria que no logro ubicar el contenido del texto entre el titulo y el precio, sino que siempre me va a quedar en la esquina inferior izquierda por mas que intento recolocarlo. Adjunto código y una imagen para ser mas claro. Cualquier idea o ayuda será agradecida. De antemano muchas gracias.

```
div.contenedorCarta{
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
        background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
        width: 30em;
        box-shadow: 0 0.5em 1em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0.5em 1em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        margin: 1em;
    }

        .contenedorCarta h3{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            text-decoration: underline;
            font-size: 1.5em;
            height: 1.5em;
            width: 70%;   
        }

        .detalleProducto{
            display: flex;
        }

        .precioProducto{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: flex-end;
            font-size: 1.3em;
            width: 40%;
            height: 1.5em;
        }
```

[image: Creo que se entiende donde esta ocurriendo mi problema.]

Comment: y tu html? Si no tienes HTML no se verá nada

Comment: @Ruslan Lopez en que sentido? Yo lo estoy haciendo con React asi que se renderiza directo en el documento. Decis que me falto ponerlo aca en la consulta?

Comment: entonces te faltó agregarle el js, pensé que ya usarías JSX o TSX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Procedimiento:

- Crea una etiqueta `article` (*una por cada card*)
- Dentro de cada una de estas insertamos la imagen
- Dentro del `article` ponemos un `div` en el cual colocamos los otros tres elementos de texto cada uno en una etiqueta `p`

Posterior:

Estarías obteniendo dentro del `article` una imagen y un div, pero ahora se presenta el detalle que la imagen quedaría arriba del artículo, para solventar eso:

- Le damos al article un display Flex

Ahora tenemos una imagen a lado de los textos, como los textos los pusimos en párrafos y están dentro del div quedarían uno sobre otro.

Los demás detalles estéticos para conseguir el aspecto de una card ya te lo dejo a ti

Propuesta de código:

```html
    <style>
      * {
        border: 0;
        margin: 0;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .card {
        border: 1px solid;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 300px;
      }
      .card-img {
        border: 1px solid;
        height: 60px;
        width: 60px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        min-height: 100%;
        border-radius: 50%;
      }
      .card-container {
        border: 1px solid;
        width: 200px;
      }
    </style>
    <article class="card">
      <span class="card-img">
      </span>
      <div class="card-container">
          <p class="card-container__text">
           Texto 1
          </p>
          <p class="card-container__text">
           Texto 2
          </p>
          <p class="card-container__text">
           Texto 3
          </p>
      </div>
    </article>
```

Y así luciría en el navegador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Nota**

- Este ejemplo es didáctico, habrá cosas como el `span` y los bordes que tal vez tendrás que remover, de modo que maquetes tus cards con la estructura esperada.

Comment: Gracias @BetaM, me la dejaste mucho mas clara para encarar la construcción de la carta. Un gusto, saludos.